# Where libraries' path are stored in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration

I have several libraries in my intelliJ and one of them has junit jar. But project is not able to compiled because classes does not see the junit jar, although it is added under libraries.

I solved this problem by adding junit jar to another library and problem solved. But I want to know where is it specified (in which file) that in which library intelliJ is looking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your project setup in Idea where they are being stored.

Either is the configuration located within the following folder structure:

`.idea`

Or within either of these files:

`*.iml, *.ipr`

^-- these files/folders is located under `/path/to/your/project/<file/path>`